# Kotlin Web Programming without Using Intelli-J Ultimate?

Tags: kotlin

I am a Java developer who has fallen in love with Kotlin.I am very new to it, but it is a Great language. I just have one problem: I also love web development. It makes it very difficult to do web development in Kotlin since every tutorial out there is in Intelli-J Ultimate Edition and I just can't swallow the cost right now. There is already not quite as much support for Kotlin online, being such a new language. Are there alternative IDE's and/or ways to use Intelli-J CE to develop Web Apps (JSP-like, Kara, HML builder) with Kotlin? The cost of Intelli-J Ultimate is forcing me to do all of my development in Intelli-J except Kotlin web development, which is annoying. And I cannot seem to find any really good alternative anyway.

Comment: I apologize if I rambled. I am sick and was up all night last night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intelij IDEA Community Edition supports HTML/CSS/JS etc all right. I believe there is no special support for Kara (and no plans for it) since Kotlin code highlighting and completion do the job.

You are right that advanced frameworks like JSP need Ultimate Edition, but since you probably do not have a fixed stack, try to choose some other alternatives. I use `kotlinx.html` with any rooting framework for HTML templating.

Comment: Thank you. Any pointers on where I could go to learn about kotlinx.html? Seems like it's hard to come by resources for learning these frameworks since Kotlin is newer.

Comment: Never heard of a tutorial on the thing or something. It looks very much like a normal HTML, and where it doesn't, code completion in IDE usually helps.